# Django setting environment variable globally

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, django, mod-python

I'm having a problem setting up Django on our CentOS server using mod_python. Site 'A' is running PHP (Codeigniter) and site 'B' is running Django. Our Django site is running perfectly.

However, every once in a while (maybe 1 or 2 requests in 10), site 'A' is giving a 404 error. With further investigation, I've discovered that there are a number of server environment variables that are being set globally by Django. For example, looking at a phpinfo() page within site A:

```
_ENV["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]  mysite.settings
_ENV["REQUEST_URI"] /path/to/my/django/site/page
```

Because all the request paths are set to my Django site URLs, Codeigniter is 404ing.

The setup in httpd.conf is that we have location tags set up within a virtualhost directive.

Can anyone help?

Comment: These are more than likely being set in your Apache configuration files (or perhaps .htaccess files). You would be doing people a service by pasting those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the answer you want to hear but here goes anyway :)

If you run your Django site under `mod_wsgi` instead of `mod_python` you will see multiple benefits:

1. Under `mod_wsgi` you can run in **daemon** mode, meaning your Django site will be isolated in its own process.  This means environment variables won't be set globally in the Apache environment (which I think in your case are being set by `mod_python`).  It also means you can restart your Django site without restarting Apache.
2. With `mod_wsgi` in **daemon** mode you will have only one instance of Python interpreter running in memory instead of one instance in each Apache process.  This is a huge memory savings, leaving you more room for caching, more Apache processes, whatever.
3. `mod_wsgi` is not just more stable, but enough that I am just one of many Django devs that slap our foreheads whenever we see someone still using `mod_python`.  Example: [tweet from Django core dev Jacob Kaplan-Moss](http://twitter.com/jacobian/status/8197144453).
4. Finally, `mod_wsgi` is faster and has excellent community support, compared to zero support and languishing bugs for `mod_python`.

Comment: I understand that mod_python isn't an ideal platform, but for various reasons mod_wsgi isn't available. I believe FastCGI might be available though, so I'll look into that. You're right, it isn't what I wanted to hear, but thanks for your answer anyway!